# Blender 日本語化したのですが文字がかすれて読めません

Tags: macos, blender

Mac 10.15.6 Blender 2.83.2を使用しています
日本語化を設定したのですが、部分的にかすれて読めないところがあります

[image: 日本語が部分的にかすれて読めない]

気がつくと読めるようになるのですが、また急に元の状態に戻ってしまいます
Blenderは始めたばかりなのですが、Blender 2.83.2でも同じ事象でした

仕方がないので英語に戻したのですが、英語も同じようにかすれてしまいます

Blenderタグの主旨とは違う内容なのかもしれないのですが、どうしようもなく質問させていただきました
原因や対処方法ご存知の方教えていただけないでしょうか

Comment: 検索すると **Blender公式サイトからダウンロードする** [Blender2.8をダウンロードして日本語化する方法！【2020年リリース版】](https://xn--r9j1d0b6i8jx814a8sl.com/blender-download/) とか **Font設定関連** あたりの記事があるようです。[Blenderの日本語化](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1042824700), [\[blender\]インターフェイスの日本語化とTextオブジェクトに日本語を使う方法](http://www.cubicanimationworks.com/2020/02/text.html), [英語UIで日本語ファイル名などの文字化けをなくす方法](https://www.cgradproject.com/archives/4928/), [無料の3DCGソフト Blenderを日本語化する方法](https://peachcle.com/how-to-japaneseize-blender/) これらを試してみるか、その辺を起点に更に検索してみるか、といったところでしょうか。

Comment: フォントの設定を変えて見たのですが完璧とも言える組み合わせが見つからず、英語に戻しました。その上で`Arial Unicode.ttf`にすると大丈夫そうなので、この(英語ですが)設定でやっていきたいと思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

日本語フォントを変えてみてください
おそらくそれで解決します

Comment: しらみつぶしまではやっていないのですが、一長一短のような感じです。あと、たまたま気付いたのですが外部ディスプレイだとカスレがほとんどありませんでした。ただ一部表示されない状態になることがあります。